# cv2 has no attribute legacy

Tags: opencv, tracker

[Image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYE1R.png)
Whenever I try to access the legacy module form opencv, it says that it can't find it. I don't know if there are any other way to get to the opencv trackers.

I read the other posts on this issue, so I only downloaded opencv-contrib-python, and deleted my old opencv which was opencv python. I did this multiple times, but nothing seems to work. Does anyone have any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: Do not post images of code. Use text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please **read** the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - And Show Code As Text, Not An Image" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).